# Is there a simple way to lower 0.5 square meters of concrete by 2mm?

Tags: concrete

When I did concreting to raise the floor in my bathroom by 15cm, I accidentally created a bump of about 0.5 square meter, which is about 2mm higher than the rest of the raised floor level.

I'm looking for a simple way to reduce the concrete level there.

I was thinking of using a rubbing brick, but I don't want to buy one if would be hopeless.

Comment: What is under it?   If you just put it on level ground and didn't prep it you could just put a lot of weight on it (spread out and centered) and it will go down eventually.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. How big and thick is this slab? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: Talk to a local tool rental store, they'll probably have something that will grind down the concrete. Doing it by hand sounds... excruciating.

Comment: 2mm? How is that a problem? Maybe describe the issue you're trying to resolve. There could be better answers.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is with an angle grinder and a concrete surfacing disk, these use carbide blocks or diamond impregnated ones that grind the surface.

2mm is not a huge amount but enough at 1/2 meter square that doing it by hand will take a really long time, using a surfacing disk is cleaner and easier than masonry grinding disks

Amazon has one similar to what I have used on small jobs (4-1/2” angle grinder)
Search for grinding wheels for concrete and masonry the more segments the disk has the better the finish and longer it will last.

After surfacing the surface is usually much smoother and looks different I have used a strong muriatic acid wash to “rough up” the surface.

Comment: You type faster than me. I agree with the surfacing disc. + Stay safe over there.

Answer (score 1):

Having ground a LOT of concrete with a rubbing brick (I have personally nearly worn one out), it won't be useless.

It will be relatively quiet, effective, and inexpensive; it will probably take less time than a trip to a tool rental store and back again to get a noisy, potentially dusty (or flinging cooling water mixed with dust) alternative for this small adjustment to a small area. It will certainly cost less.